# Javascript (jquery.ui.slider) - Alternative to current global method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

### Basic Javascript Question - Alternative to current global method?

I'll start off by saying I don't have a large amount of experience with Javascript, but have 'dabbled' with it on and off for many years (mostly to do basic jquery powered things and some form calculations).

Currently I am putting together a calculator with a jquery.ui based slider.  I have it functioning well, but last night hit a problem that I had to use global variables to work around, and while it works now, I don't feel this is the correct solution.

I started off with a line like this in a Calculation function outside of the slider, being called on the slide event from within the slider.  I could have moved the math up inside the slider, but it's used for other things and I'd prefer to keep it as an outside function I can call when needed:

```
savings = Math.round(cost[$('.selectable-div.selected').attr('id')] * $( "#slider-gallons" ).slider( "value" ); );
```

... But it would always end up calculating based on wherever the slider 'started', not where it currently was, presumably because "value" is only changed after the slider is moved, not during?  So if I was on position 1, and moved to 2, it would then display me the result for 1.  When I moved from position 2 to position 3, it would display the result for position 2.  When I moved back from 3 to 2, it would display me the result for position 3 (whichever I was 'last' on).

I had another small piece of code within the slider using the ui.value, that it would update in real-time, position 1 showed 1, position 2 showed 2, etc.  This is where my question stems, I don't know how to call that "slider gallons" ui.value outside of the slider function itself (I.E. inside my calculate function).

As a work-around, I defined ui.value as a global variable "var_slider_gallons_pos" and called it like this:

```
savings = Math.round(cost[$('.selectable-div.selected').attr('id')] * var_slider_gallons_pos );
```

It works great, but I'm not happy with it.  Is there another way to do this, I.E. (and I know the code below doesn't work, just a pipe-dream example of what i am looking for).  I just want something where I can call on the slider ui.value directly without needing those extra variables floating around.

```
savings = Math.round(cost[$('.selectable-div.selected').attr('id')] * $( "#slider-gallons" ).slider( ui.value ); );
```

I don't know if that makes sense, but I'm trying to call the slider element's ui.value without having to first create a variable from within the slider event.

I'm sure this is some basic element I'm overlooking because I am not well versed in javascript, so hopefully someone can help me out.

EDIT:
For completeness, here is my full slider and calculator code I am currently using.

Slider:

```
$( "#slider-gallons" ).slider({
        value:250,
        min: 250,
        max: 3000,
        step: 250,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var_slider_gallons_pos = ui.value;
            $( "#slider-gallons-amount" ).html( "Your facility produces <span>" + var_slider_gallons_pos + "</span> Gallons of waste oil each year");
            recalculateSavings();
        }
    });

    /* these lines exist to populate the text values on load */
    /* I could probably do the var_slider_gallons_pos part differently here as well */

    var_slider_gallons_pos = $( "#slider-gallons" ).slider( "value" );
    $( "#slider-gallons-amount" ).html( "Your facility produces <span>" + $( "#slider-gallons" ).slider( "value" ) + "</span> Gallons of waste oil each year");
```

And the calculate function:

```
function recalculateSavings() {
        var cost = {
            'calc-choice-natural-gas': 1.53,
            'calc-choice-electric': 4.86,
            'calc-choice-propane': 4.37,
            'calc-choice-fuel-oil': 3.74
        };

            /* this is the line causing me grief */
        savings = Math.round(cost[$('.selectable-div.selected').attr('id')] * var_slider_gallons_pos );
    $('#savings-calculator .calc-savings-one-year .savings').html('$' + formatNumber(savings));
    $('#savings-calculator .calc-savings-multiple-years .savings').html('$' + formatNumber(savings * var_slider_years_pos ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way!

I am still not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I'm satisfied with it.

I added the following code to the slide function, just above "recalculateSavings();"

```
$(this).slider('value', ui.value);
```

And then used in the math function.

```
$( "#slider-gallons" ).slider( "value" );
```

This must force the value to be updated to ui.value before moving on to the recalculate piece, which seems to do the trick for real time updating of the calculation result.  This allowed me to get rid of all the global functions.